# PHP: Make an array clear?

Tags: php

I have an array like this:

```
array(
    [cat] => news,
    [comments_count] => 2,
    [meta] => array(
        [first_meta] => 44,
        [second_meta] => 54,    
    )
)
```

The above code is an example of array that I have. Now I wanna make the above array clear like this:

```
array(
    [cat] => news,
    [comments_count] => 2,
    [first_meta] => 44,
    [second_meta] => 54,    
)
```

(means Delete -meta- but not it's indexes. I want to add indexes of meta to the first array)

Comment: Add your code also to see where is the problem.

Comment: can you be a bit more precise? do you want this as generic solution (do this for all arrays in your array), or just one time for the particular `meta` array?

Comment: @kaddath just for meta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the below function if you have a multidimentional array and you can reuse it anywhere.

```
function array_flatten($array) { 
  if (!is_array($array)) { 
    return false; 
  } 
  $result = array(); 
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) { 
    if (is_array($value)) { 
      $result = array_merge($result, array_flatten($value)); 
    } else { 
      $result[$key] = $value; 
    } 
  } 
  return $result; 
}

$array = array(
'cat' => 'news',
'comments_count' => '2',
'meta' => array(
 'first_meta' => '44',
 'second_meta' => '54',    
                 )
);

var_dump(array_flatten($array));
```

The result will be

```
array(4) {
  ["cat"]=>
  string(4) "news"
  ["comments_count"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["first_meta"]=>
  string(2) "44"
  ["second_meta"]=>
  string(2) "54"
}
```

Otherwise if you just need to flatten `meta` array as in your question. `array_merge()` the meta array and unset `meta` it as below.

```
$result = array_merge($array, $array["meta"]);
unset($result["meta"]);
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 4):

Add the `meta` array to the array and then `unset` the `meta` array:

```
$array = $array + $array['meta'];
unset($array['meta']);
```